# In Poland, is/are there any region dangerous for non-white people to visit?

Tags: safety, poland

From 2016, Poland saw the [rise of right-wing nationalists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VbBblICX8k).

In Poland, are there any cities or special regions in cities which are dangerous for non-white people to go to?

I mean, are there any cities or areas in cities in which predominantly white supremacists live and they are antagonistic to non-white people, and which are dangerous as a result?

Comment: Such questions cannot be answered, since these are actions on individuals and in most cases minorities. The same question can be asked for white travellers in Africa, but also not be answered with any form of reliability.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, see [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157731/in-germany-are-there-any-cities-or-special-regions-in-cities-which-are-dangerou).

Comment: And? What does that answer prove, other that the same question is being asked there as here. See [Crime Index by Country 2020](https://www.numbeo.com/crime/rankings_by_country.jsp), where of 129 countries Poland ranks 109 (Germany 90). You must look at the whole picture.

Comment: I was in Poland for a few weeks around January and saw far less nationalism on display there than in the one day I spent in Hungary a few weeks later. In Gdansk one guy in my hostel was from an African country and chose Poland to have a holiday from the other European country he now lives in. He didn't mention any negative experiences and I didn't see anyone treat him differently. I did have one local friend in Gdansk who was a nationalist but counterintuitively didn't seem racist. He wanted to welcome Ukrainian refugees but not African/Middle Eastern/muslim refugees, which does seem racist \:

Comment: I'm Polish. I wouldn't say it's dangerous and I don't think race matters that much in Poland as it does in the USA for example. If you go to a bigger city you will find a lot of people of a different race. In small cities, people treat it more like an attraction because they rarely see people of a different race, it's nothing bad and it's usually not racist. In general, Poland is much safer than the USA even for non-whites.

Comment: @Konrad, *I'm Polish. I wouldn't say it's dangerous and ...* --- I need views from non-Polish, as pains of foreigner travelers cannot be perceived by a native.

Comment: @user366312 Check on youtube, there's a couple of foreign vloggers there who share their experiences

Comment: @Konrad, are they non-white vloggers?

Comment: @user366312 yes

Comment: @Konrad, so, you can help me by supplying at least one link, or you can post your view as an answer. :)

Comment: @user366312 https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=black+living+in+poland

Comment: @Konrad, Thanks but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @user366312 have a look at this video https://youtu.be/ZaDjIQ4BSec and others by the same guy - a black British tourist in Krakow and other parts of Poland.

Answer (score 3):

No problems whatsoever. People of different nationality or race are treated with respect and people seems very friendly. I suppose that if you go to a nightclub in a dodgy area it may be risky, but definitely not because of your race.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what you may have seen in the media, Poland is generally far less racist than most other European countries - certainly in my experience (White British tourist) I've never witnessed anything there - and the same cannot be said for Germany, France or the UK.

There's several videos on YouTube from coloured travellers who have visited Poland - I came across [this one](https://youtu.be/ZaDjIQ4BSec) recently.

Comment: *certainly in my experience (White British tourist) I've never witnessed anything there* --- so may I say politely that you are not qualified to answer this question? This question can only be answered either by a Polish or a Colored tourist.